# Broken link - Distributed Sending and Blockout Dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I am diving into the documentation regarding the Marketing Cloud Email Studio Summer '22 Release Notes.

With reference to 'Distributed Sending and Blockout Dates Are No Longer Available' there appears to be little information. I was looking online for more information but clicking on the link the page returns error 404:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_ds_distributed_sending.htm&type=5 (I attach image).

[image]

Do you know why? Does anyone use the Distributed Sending and Blockout Dates? Can you give me information?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Where did you find that link? I don't use them (never heard of them, but I'm not a SFMC person), but [Searching SF Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/search-result?language=en_US#q=mc%20ds%20distribured%20sending&t=allResultsTab&sort=relevancy&f:@sflanguage=[en_US]) brings up this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2022_summer_es_ds_EOL.htm&type=5 (which simply states, *"Distributed Sending and Blockout Dates have been retired from all Salesforce orgs."*) and this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358796&type=1

Comment: Hi, the link I posted https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_ds_distributed_sending.htm&type=5 I found on the net by searching for Distributed Sending.

Yes, I saw the guide and wanted to know what functionality they had and how they were used. 
Thank you for your comment.